# Referencing/Using an Array From Another Method..?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, methods, void

I need to be able to use the randomNumbers[] array in my button click void but if I put what is in the  void randomNumbers()  in my button click void, every time I click the button it over wrights the original Random Order Generated. Which is not what i want. Is there any way I can call/reference/use/import randomNumbers from its own void to the button click void.

Background Knowledge:

My overall objective was originally populate an array with 90 numbers from 0 - 90 in a random order with no duplicates and make them appear in a text box upon button click. After days of trying different ways, Im using this one and its the closest i've come as there are no duplicates. When I had the randomNumbers[] in the button click void the rich text boxes would display the numbers perfectly apart from it would display them all at once not one by one every time i clicked the button, so i created another 2 text boxes which display numbers one by one, but duplicates happened as every time I clicked the button the randomNumbers[] would regenerate in a different order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    void randomNumbers()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 90).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

    }

    string space = " ";
    int number;

   void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int[] array = randomNumbers;
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += randomNumbers[i].ToString() + space;
            richTextBox2.Text += array[i].ToString() + space;
            number = array[i];

        }

        textBox1.Text += number.ToString() + space;
        textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Move the declaration (not the assignment) of `randomNumbers` to the `class` instead of the `method`.

Comment: I tried that and then got errors on var and rnd ...

Comment: Check the answer I posted, should help you out pretty well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private int[] array;
   private int mouseClickCount=0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GenerateRandomNumbers();
    }


    void GenerateRandomNumbers()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        array = Enumerable.Range(1, 90).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    }


   void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(mouseClickCount == 90)
       {
          mouseClickCount =0;
          richTextBox1.Clear();
       } 
        mouseClickCount++;
        richTextBox1.Text+=randomNumbers[mouseClickCount]+ " ";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the fact that your array is local to the `void randomNumbers()` method.

The solution is really quite simple; move `randomNumbers` to be a `class` wide variable, OR (the more elegant solution) change the return type of `randomNumbers` to be an `int[]` array. I.e.:

### Option A:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] GenerateRandomNumbers()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 90).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        }

        string space = " ";
        int number;

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] array = GenerateRandomNumbers();
            for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += randomNumbers[i].ToString() + space;
                richTextBox2.Text += array[i].ToString() + space;
                number = array[i];
            }

            textBox1.Text += number.ToString() + space;
            textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to retain the list `class`-wide or *not change* once it's instanced, you should make it a variable that is `class`-scoped:

### Option B:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] randomNumbers;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randomNumbers = GenerateRandomNumbers();
        }

        int[] GenerateRandomNumbers()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 90).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        }

        string space = " ";
        int number;

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] array = randomNumbers;
            for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += randomNumbers[i].ToString() + space;
                richTextBox2.Text += array[i].ToString() + space;
                number = array[i];
            }

            textBox1.Text += number.ToString() + space;
            textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't test it, but it should work for you.

Edit: Just tested it, works fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
      public class generate
        {
    public static int[] randomNumbers()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 90).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        return randomNumbers;

    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }




    string space = " ";
    int number;

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int[] array = generate.randomNumbers();
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += randomNumbers[i].ToString() + space;
            richTextBox2.Text += array[i].ToString() + space;
            number = array[i];

        }

        textBox1.Text += number.ToString() + space;
        textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();

    }

}
  }
```

Try this.